# App/Script consumes too much memory. Ubuntu may be killing it. How do I verify/check this assumption?

Tags: command-line, scripts, python, vps

- Hosted on Digital Ocean
- Ubuntu 14.04
- 1GB RAM, 30GB HDD

I am running a python script that is reading a 200MB+ file line by line. Each line is parsed into a JSON object and then appended to an array. The application exits, or ends prematurely, after the array gets very large.

I've done some testing and error tracing to ensure that the issue is the array's increasing size. I'm listening for and printing any exceptions, but none are ever raised by the Python code.

**Example output:**

```
...
line check:  41000
line check:  42000
line check:  43000
line check:  44000
line check:  45000
dannyb@twitter-data-mining:/var/www/cmd$
```

**Question**

Does Ubuntu keep a log of applications it has killed? Does Ubuntu offer any troubleshooting techniques/options that can be used to diagnose why this script is terminating early?

Comment: If you shared your code, we could help you to optimize its memory usage. However, it would be best if you opened a new question for that on [codereview.se] and place the link here. I guess I could quickly find a few ways to improve it.

Comment: @ByteCommander, at your suggestion, I have created a topic on Code Review. You can find a link for it: [HERE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118073/data-analytics-on-static-file-of-50-000-tweets).

Also, it may be worth noting that I just doubled the available RAM on my VPS. My data-parser.py script is now able to load twice as many lines into memory, but still fails in the same way before reaching the end of the file.

Smaller files can load fully, and the program executes as expected (: